# $\text{diam}(\Omega)$ is $\geq$ to at least one side of the minimal rectangular box containing $\Omega$?

Tags: geometry, euclidean-geometry

For $\Omega\subset\mathbb{R}^n$ open and bounded, is it always the case that $\text{diam}(\Omega)$ is greater or equal to at least one side of the minimal rectangular box containing $\Omega$ ? *Added* : the sides of the minimal rectangular box are required to be parallel to the axes.

It looks true, but I can't prove it.

For a circle the minimal rectangular box would be a square and we would have equality.

For a square (with sides parallel to the axes), the minimal rectangular box would be the square itself and we would have a strict inequality, as the diagonal of a square is strictly greater in length than its sides.

Comment: do the rectangles have the sides parallel to the axes of R^n?

Comment: @insignia Yes they do.

Comment: the side length of minimal box is equal to the maximum of the set S where S is the set of supremal lengths of $\Omega$ measured along each axis of $R^n$, all of which is less than or equal to the diameter